# React native expo record video with camera and play audio at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to play audio and record video with camera at the same time on react native (expo). Then the audio must be recorded with the video.

Answer (score 0):

With OBS studio you can record some webcams, monitors, audio in and out. https://obsproject.com/de/download

I think that is waht you are looking for.
have a nice day